# How can i run mysqli "select " query under nested while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to execute "select query" between two nested while loops in mysqli queries but it's not working.

```
Table Structure

Id  ArticleId   UserIp
----------------------
1    10       116.202.34.165
2    99       106.220.38.195  
3    10       116.202.34.165  
4    25       74.192.24.105
```

Above have table structure

```
/*** Get All Unique IP Address List ***/
$userip=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select distinct(UserIp) from pageview where date between date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) and now()");

/*** Get All Unique Articles List ***/
$articleid=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select distinct(ArticleId) from pageview where date between date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) and now()");

/*** Fetch IP List ***/
while($iplist=mysqli_fetch_array($userip)){

/*** Fetch Article List ***/
    while($articlelist=mysqli_fetch_array($articleid)){
        $usrip= $iplist['UserIp'];
        $artid= $articlelist['ArticleId'];

    /*** Get Unique Visiter List ***/
        $unique_data= mysqli_query($dbcon,"select * from pageview where UserIp='$usrip' and ArticleId='$artid' ");

    }
}
```

I have required total unique visitor.
1) If 1 UserIp have two times same article id so we have to exclude that, Otherwise we have to count and print total views.

Comment: It's not working is a little bit generic....

Comment: Yes technically it's possible, so the problem is elsewhere. Turn on mysqli error reporting to find out, However it is never advised to run a query in a loop, you are supposed to use a single query with JOIN instead.

Comment: Give me some suggestion how is it possible with join?? @YourCommonSense